# Why do I get a List when I create a Seq

Tags: scala, collections

Why do I get a List when I create Seq using the following code?

```
    scala> val s = Seq[Int]()
    s: Seq[Int] = List()
```

In fact, Seq is a trait and trait cannot be initialized. What't the magic behind the scene

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Seq` is a trait, `List` is a (default) implementation.

```
object Seq extends SeqFactory.Delegate[Seq](List)
//                                          ^^^^
```

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.10/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.scala#L39

```
implicitly[List[Int] <:< Seq[Int]] // compiles, i.e. List[Int] is a subtype of Seq[Int]
```

> `Seq` is a trait and trait cannot be initialized

Firstly, even if `X` is a trait you can instantiate an anonymous class extending the trait: `new X {}`. (By the way, `List` is also an abstract class.)

Secondly, `Seq[Int]()` is desugared into `Seq.apply[Int]()` and you refer to not the trait `Seq` but its companion object.

Answer (score 4):

There is no magic.

There is simply some code which looks roughly like this:

```scala
object Seq:
  def apply[A](elements: A*) = List(elements: _*)
```

In other words, [`Seq.apply`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/immutable/Seq$.html#apply-67f) delegates to [`List.apply`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/immutable/List$.html#apply-2f), so when you call `Seq(1, 2, 3)`, it delegates to `List(1, 2, 3)`, which returns a [`List`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html).

[Here is an extremely simplified runnable Scastie demonstration](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JoergWMittag/yzD0Da8vRBiOkHCpZLVm5g):

```scala
enum MyList[+A]:
  case MyNil
  case MyCons(head: A, tail: MyList[A])

object MySeq:
  def apply[A](elements: A*) =
    elements.foldRight(MyList.MyNil: MyList[A]) { (x, xs) =>
      MyList.MyCons(x, xs)
    }

MySeq()        //=> MyNil: MyList[Nothing]

MySeq(1, 2, 3) //=> MyCons(1, MyCons(2, MyCons(3, MyNil))): MyList[Int]
```

The real code is of course more general and abstract than this simple example. The [`Seq`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/immutable/Seq$.html) object [does not have an `apply` method of its own](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.scala#L39-L44). Instead, it inherits from [`SeqFactory.Delegate[Seq](List)`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/SeqFactory$$Delegate.html):

```scala
object Seq extends SeqFactory.Delegate[Seq](List) {
//         ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
  override def from[E](it: IterableOnce[E]): Seq[E] = ???
}
```

[`SeqFactory.Delegate[Seq](List)`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/Factory.scala#L303-L308)'s [`apply` method](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/Factory.scala#L304), in turn, delegates to the `apply` method of the object which was passed as the `delegate` argument:

```scala
object SeqFactory {
  class Delegate[CC[A]](delegate: SeqFactory[CC]) extends SeqFactory[CC] {
  //                    ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
    override def apply[A](elems: A*): CC[A] = delegate.apply(elems: _*)
  //                                          ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
  }
```

The [`delegate` argument](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.scala#L39), if you remember, was the [`List` object](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/immutable/List$.html):

```scala
object Seq extends SeqFactory.Delegate[Seq](List) {
//                                          ↑↑↑↑
  override def from[E](it: IterableOnce[E]): Seq[E] = ???
}
```

[`List` doesn't have its own `apply` method](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/immutable/List$.html#apply-2f), instead it [inherits it from `IterableFactory`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/IterableFactory.html#apply-2f), which [looks like this](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/Factory.scala#L103):

```scala
def apply[A](elems: A*): CC[A] = from(elems)
```

So, it just delegates to [`from`, which is an abstract method](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/IterableFactory.html#from-1dd) which [it implements](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/immutable/List$.html#from-fffff6c8) like [this](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L684):

```scala
def from[B](coll: collection.IterableOnce[B]): List[B] = Nil.prependedAll(coll)
```

So, `from` delegates to `Nil.prependedAll`. `Nil` [inherits `prependedAll`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/immutable/Nil$.html#prependedAll-fffff6c8) from [`List`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#prependedAll-fffff6c8), where it [looks like this](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L146-L165):

```scala
override def prependedAll[B >: A](prefix: collection.IterableOnce[B]): List[B] = prefix match {
  case xs: List[B] => xs ::: this
  case _ if prefix.knownSize == 0 => this
  case b: ListBuffer[B] if this.isEmpty => b.toList
  case _ =>
    val iter = prefix.iterator
    if (iter.hasNext) {
      val result = new ::[B](iter.next(), this)
      var curr = result
      while (iter.hasNext) {
        val temp = new ::[B](iter.next(), this)
        curr.next = temp
        curr = temp
      }
      releaseFence()
      result
    } else {
      this
    }
}
```

In your case, where you are constructing an empty `Seq`, you will hit [the second case](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L148):

```scala
case _ if prefix.knownSize == 0 => this
```

Which just returns `this`, which is `Nil`, which is an instance of `List[A]`. Therefore, the *runtime class* of `Seq[Int]()` is `List[Int]`, but of course, the *static type* is still `Seq[Int]`.

The most general case is the fourth case, which gets the `iterator` of the `prefix` and then loops over the `iterator` in a `while` loop. Note: this is *not* "the Scala way"! The Scala standard library takes some shortcuts in the interest of performance and/or platform interoperability and/or simply caused by the fact that at this particular point in the library, the high-level abstractions we are used to are not available, because it is the standard library which provides those abstractions in the first place.

The Scala way to do this would be a [*fold*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)), like I did above.

So, even though the real Scala library goes through half a dozen additional layers of indirection, it is pretty much equivalent to the simplified code snippet I wrote above.

Answer (score 3):

You called [`apply`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq$.html#apply%5BA%5D(elems:A*):CC%5BA%5D) from the `Seq` companion object. The implementation of `apply` returned a `List[Int]`, which is an instance of `Seq[Int]`